# Mutlple owl Carousel in one page with different setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, owl-carousel

There are two owlCarousel working perfectly in one page but I want to change the default setting on each carousel. Once I changed the effects applying to both carousel.

What I've already tried

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel1({
        navigation : false,
        pagination : true,
        items : 1
      });
    });

</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#owl-example").owlCarousel();


    });
</script>
```

I want to change the below settings for each carousle

```
 $.fn.owlCarousel.options = {

        items : 4,
        itemsCustom : false,
        itemsDesktop : [1199, 1],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [979, 1],
        itemsTablet : [768, 1],
        itemsTabletSmall : false,
        itemsMobile : [479, 1],
        singleItem : false,
        itemsScaleUp : false
}
```

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions carefully; this question is not about [tag:owl], whose description is "The Web Ontology Language (OWL) is a vocabulary for creating schemas (ontologies), i.e. definitions of classes, properties and the relationships between them."  You should have used the [tag:owl-carousel] tag.

Answer (score 5):

If you assign a variable to each of the div's you wish to target and then assign the options, example below;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var one = $("#one");
   var two = $("#two");

  one.owlCarousel({
      navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      singleItem:true,
      mouseDrag:false,
      touchDrag:false
  });  

two.owlCarousel({
  navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
  slideSpeed : 300,
  paginationSpeed : 400,
  singleItem:true,
  mouseDrag:false,
  touchDrag:false,
  navigationText : false,
  rewindSpeed : 300,
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

there are tow things you must do to let every owl slider have its own trigger

*1- each one have it's own assignment like above*

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   var one = $("#one");
   var two = $("#two");

  one.owlCarousel({
      navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      singleItem:true,
      mouseDrag:false,
      touchDrag:false
  });  

two.owlCarousel({
  navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
  slideSpeed : 300,
  paginationSpeed : 400,
  singleItem:true,
  mouseDrag:false,
  touchDrag:false,
  navigationText : false,
  rewindSpeed : 300,
  });

});
```

*2- change the button class name* 

**1st slider**

```
<div class="customNavigation">
                    <a class="btn prev_one"><i class="fa fa-backward" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn next_one"><i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn play_one"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn stop_one"><i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
```

**2nd Slider**

```
<div class="customNavigation">
                    <a class="btn prev_two"><i class="fa fa-backward" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn next_two"><i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn play_two"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn stop_two"><i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
```

I wish it could be fine for you all

Answer (score 0):

To change the class of the nav or dots you can use the class options provided by Owl Carousel (https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-classes.html)

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
   var one = $("#one");
   var two = $("#two");

  one.owlCarousel({
      navContainerClass: '//YOUR CUSTOM CLASS',
      dotsClass: '//YOUR CUSTOM CLASS'
  });  

  two.owlCarousel({
    navContainerClass: '//YOUR CUSTOM CLASS',
    dotsClass: '//YOUR CUSTOM CLASS'
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

js code

```
    $("#fr-car").owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: false,
    autoplay: true,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    autoplayTimeout: 3000,
    nav: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: true
  });
  $('#nd-car').owlCarousel({
    responsive:{
      0:{
          items:1,
          nav:true
      },
      600:{
          items:3,
          nav:false
      },
      1000:{
          items:5,
          nav:true,
          loop:false
      }
  }
  })
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="fr-car" class="owl-carousel">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div


<div id="nd-car" class="owl-carousel" >
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div
```

Comment: When adding an answer to an almost six year old question it is important to point out in the explanation not only how and why it works, but also what advantages this code offers over the three existing answers.