# Owl carousel in multiple boxes, different showcase

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I would like multiple *owl carousels* on my webpage. My only problem is that in one box i need only one Item showcased and in another box i need 3 items and my script is referring to both. How could i target them to have these things different.[check the example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxJ8X.jpg). I read something about carousel data but i don't think it helps.

Comment: Let's see your attempt at coding this.  Does this help you get started? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39686010/3825777 or? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888864/mutlple-owl-carousel-in-one-page-with-different-setting or? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45630974/3825777  Maybe this jsfiddle helps? https://jsfiddle.net/wtg76spd/1/

Comment: I checked it. It combines the two, and i need exactly the oposite, as you see in your example he put for both items 6. A new thing I saw that might help me get started was the fact that he used 2 Id's. I'll try copying the code and change some things up

Comment: I found the solution, put two classes: DEMO and DEMO1 and called owl carousel funcion on them, and it works haha nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add two different classes, ex: `demo` and `demo1` and call the function on them:

```
$('.demo').owlCarousel({}
$('.demo1').owlCarousel({}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an id for each carousel in your page. for example you could try this:

```
<div id="box-1" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">...</div> 
<div id="box-2" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">...</div>
```

In your JavaScript code

```
  $('#box-1').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    //... more options
 });

  $('#box-2').owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    //... more options
  });
```

That's what worked for me for my web project. please let me know if it works for you too.

check out the documentation https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html